Class extension don't work when I want to login
I have a problem when I want to extend the class and call the NewTest class with the login function URL open but after that nothing happens, the test does not continue with login, function is not executed.
This is the class where I load URL from file properties.
package base;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class BaseTest {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static Properties props = new Properties();
    public static FileReader fr;
    
    @BeforeTest
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if(driver == null) {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\stefa\\eclipse-workspace\\New folder\\selenium\\src\\test\\resources\\configfiles\\config.properties");
            props.load(fr);
        }
        if(props.getProperty("browser").equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
            driver.get(props.getProperty("baseUrl"));
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
    }
}

This is the class where I extend the previous class and continue with login form.
package testcase;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import base.BaseTest;

public class NewTest extends BaseTest {
    @Test
    public static void loginTest(String[] args) {
        WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.id("user-name"));
        userName.sendKeys("standard_user");
        
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
        password.sendKeys("secret_sauce");
        
        WebElement loginBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("login-button"));
        loginBtn.click();
    }
}

I can't login to the page.

(1) which language is this? (2) you have posted the same code twice

This Selenium Java if that was the question, I'm sorry for posting the same code twice.

There are multiple issues with your code sample.

You have a main() method annotated as a @Test method. I don't think TestNG will discover your main() method as a suite level method. The same goes for your @Test method as well
Assuming that somehow TestNG discovers your main() as a configuration method and invokes it, you would still have your driver as null because you are declaring a local variable (also called as driver) and initialising the ChromeDriver instance to it. So when TestNG exits the method, the driver instance goes out of scope and so your class level static data member would never have gotten initialised ( I believe this is called as shadowing in java.

Please find below a cleaned up version of your code.
The point to note here is that, I use ThreadLocal variable for setting up and clearing your WebDriver instance, so that even if you decide to run your @Test methods in parallel (at some point in the future), your code is still thread safe.
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Properties;

public class BaseTest {

    private final ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private static final Properties props = new Properties();

    @BeforeSuite
    public void readProperties() throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("src/test/resources/configfiles/config.properties");
        props.load(fr);
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setupDriver() {
        if (props.getProperty("browser").equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            WebDriver localDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            localDriver.get(props.getProperty("baseUrl"));
            localDriver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.set(localDriver);
        }
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void closeDriver() {
        if (driver.get() != null) {
            driver.get().quit();
            driver.remove();
        }
    }

    public final WebDriver driver() {
        return Objects.requireNonNull(driver.get(), "No valid driver instance found.");
    }
}

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class NewTest extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    public void loginTest() {
        WebElement userName = driver().findElement(By.id("user-name"));
        userName.sendKeys("standard_user");

        WebElement password = driver().findElement(By.id("password"));
        password.sendKeys("secret_sauce");

        WebElement loginBtn = driver().findElement(By.id("login-button"));
        loginBtn.click();
    }
}

